# Breakpoints not triggered in a method with yield-return

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, yield-return

My function is like this

```
 IEnumerable<IPublishedContent> GetAllowedBlogs(IEnumerable<IPublishedContent> blogLandingNodes)
{
    foreach (var node in blogLandingNodes)
    {
        if ("Condition")
        {
            var blogsToDisplay = GetPostsForBlog(node);

            foreach (var blog in blogsToDisplay)
            {
                yield return blog;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            var blogsToDisplay = GetPostsForBlog(node, catId);

            foreach (var blog in blogsToDisplay)
            {
                yield return blog;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When i put a break point and check I can see result nodes yielding, But when i check here

```
  IEnumerable<IPublishedContent> posts1 = GetAllowedBlogs(node);
```

I get nothing, What is that I am doing wrong?

Comment: `GetAllowedBlogs()` only returns an _iterator_. The code inside is transformed into a state machine by the compiler and is only executed if you _use the iterator_, for example if you `foreach` over `posts1`.

Comment: What are you "checking" and how?

Comment: Good explanations can be found for example [here](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter6/IteratorBlockImplementation.aspx) and [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/359873/Csharp-Iterator-Pattern-demystified)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because all 'yielders' are converted to a lazy-enumeration.

```
IEnumerable<IPublishedContent> posts1 = GetAllowedBlogs(node);
```

This line only **creates** the enumeration of Blogs, but **does not execute it**.
Nothing really  ran yet.

Try this one and see if your breakpoint worked:

```
 IEnumerable<IPublishedContent> posts1 = GetAllowedBlogs(node).ToList();
```

(.ToList is from System.Linq namespace of course)

FYI: this is not the point of the question, but you may find it interesting to see what `yield` really compiles into. The code and explanation under this link may be a little old, but main points will still apply: http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter6/IteratorBlockImplementation.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Lazy Evaluation.

You won't begin to run through the code until you start using posts1.

Answer (score 0):

You should materialize the sequence by calling one of methods like ToList ToArray etc. that will actually execute your code.